# Windows form Quiz tracking radio buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, radio-button

I could use some help with setting up a windows form quiz for a class project.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //I'm using p to track the amount of points the user collects through the quiz.

        int p = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #region Submit Button & Point Calculation
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Calculating the amount of point the user collected after submitting his answers.
            switch (p)
            {
                case 1:
                    radioButton1c.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    radioButton2a.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    radioButton3b.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    radioButton4c.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    radioButton5a.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    radioButton6a.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    radioButton7c.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    radioButton8d.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    radioButton9a.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    radioButton10b.Checked = true;
                    p++;
                    break;
                }
            MessageBox.Show($"You have collected {p} amount of points.");
        }
    }
}
```

so far, this is what I have for a class project. I basically have a visual studio windows form with a label and a groupbox with 4 radio boxes. `radioBox1c.Checked = True` was me trying to check if that specific one was checked in that group. then it moves on to `radiobox"XX"`.Checked and does the same. And if it is checked, it would add to `p`. My problem is that I cant run it because I has errors. I've tried using a whole lot of `if` instead of switch but I got lost. It shows that the user collects 0 points no matter what answer is selected, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Please update the post with what errors are being returned.

Comment: Sorry, I found the issue, 2 of the curly brackets were erased while I was revising code. I fixed them in the dump Sorry. The only issue I have is         MessageBox.Show($"You have collected {p} amount of points.");
          currently it doesnt seem to increase the value of p

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //I'm using p to track the amount of points the user collects through the quiz.

        int p=0;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Calculating the amount of point the user collected after submitting his answers.
            if (radioButton1c.Checked == true)
            {
            p++;
            }
            if (radioButton2a.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton3b.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton4c.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton5a.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton6a.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton7c.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton8d.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton9a.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (radioButton10b.Checked == true)
            {
                p++;
            }


            MessageBox.Show($"You have earned {p} point(s).");

            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Managed to fix my own issue. I went ahead and used if instead of a switch and everything seemed to just work.